Does the complex interpolation space $(L^1(\mathbb{R}),W^{2,1}(\mathbb{R}))_{\frac{1}{2}}$ continuously embed into $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$?
The complex interpolation space between $(L^p(\mathbb{R}),W^{2,p}(\mathbb{R}))_\theta$ with interpolation parameter $\theta=\frac{1}{2}$ is known to be $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R})$ for $1<p<\infty$. As far as I know there is no known good representation of the complex interpolation space when $p=1$ (as in the title).
However, we know that it is embedded in certain spaces such the Besov space $B^1_{1,\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, but none of the results I am aware of are strong enough to deduce that $(L^1(\mathbb{R}),W^{2,1}(\mathbb{R}))_{\frac{1}{2}} \subset L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ (analogous to the Sobolev embedding for $W^{1,1}(\mathbb{R})\subset L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$).
My question is then exactly this (see the title). The usual counter example for such Sobolev embeddings is the function $\log|\log|x||$ (with suitable cutoff as $x\to\infty$). As such, I would alternatively appreciate any suggestions on how to show if $\log|\log|x|| \in \left(L^1(B),W^{2,1}(B)\right)_{\frac{1}{2}}$ for the unit ball $B=[-1,1]\subset\mathbb{R}$?
